# Error 125002 while trying to read messages from huawei modem

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

so i want to read some sms received in my huawei modem.
for this i have to take a token value from one page and reuse it in another pages (sms-list) of my modem

but i got this error 125002 which means that my token value is not accurate

here is my code

```
import hashlib
import base64
import binascii
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASEURL = 'http://192.168.8.1'


session = requests.Session()
reqresponse = session.get(BASEURL + '/api/webserver/SesTokInfo')
if reqresponse.status_code == 200:
        root = ET.fromstring(reqresponse.text)
        for results in root.iter('SesInfo'):
            sessionid = results.text
            print("the sessionId is", sessionid)
        for results in root.iter('TokInfo'):
            token = results.text
            print("The token is", token)
        sessioncookies = reqresponse.cookies

post_data = '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>\n'
post_data += '<request><PageIndex>1</PageIndex><ReadCount>3</ReadCount><BoxType>1</BoxType><SortType>0</SortType><Ascending>0</Ascending><UnreadPreferred>1</UnreadPreferred></request>\n'

headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8',
               '__RequestVerificationToken': token,'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'}

api_url = BASEURL + '/api/sms/sms-list'
logonresponse = session.post( api_url, data=post_data, headers=headers, cookies=sessioncookies)


result = BeautifulSoup(logonresponse.text, 'html.parser')

for r in result:
    print(r)
```

from this bash script, i m getting all my message list and it is almost the same principle

```
RESPONSE=`curl -s -X GET http://192.168.8.1/api/webserver/SesTokInfo`
COOKIE=`echo "$RESPONSE"| grep SessionID=| cut -b 10-147`
TOKEN=`echo "$RESPONSE"| grep TokInfo| cut -b 10-41`


DATA="<request><PageIndex>1</PageIndex><ReadCount>3</ReadCount> 
<BoxType>1</BoxType><SortType>0</SortType><Ascending>0</Ascending> 
<UnreadPreferred>1</UnreadPreferred></request>"

curl -b $COOKIE -c $COOKIE -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" --data 
"$DATA" http://192.168.8.1/api/sms/sms-list --header 
"__RequestVerificationToken: $TOKEN" --header "Content-Type:text/xml"
```

what did i missed in python please?

Comment: That doesn't look like a Python error message or a Bash error. Where do you see this? Are you on Windows?

Comment: You are adding an XML declaration at the beginning of your `post_data` in the Python script but not in the Bash script. Also, tangentially, the end of the Python `post_data` seems to be missing (did you copy/paste from an Emacs window which obscures the end of long lines?)

Comment: yes i correct it, i m workin on raspbian raspberry

Comment: So the error message is the HTTP response you get from the device?

Comment: yes it comes from HTTP and i think it is because of this "token" value which is not matching but idk why , i m following the same principle in the bash code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i finally solve my problem, obviously i was not getting the right token and session id value.

here is my final code

```
import hashlib
import base64
import binascii
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xmltodict
import os


 BASEURL = 'http://192.168.8.1'


 session = requests.Session()
 reqresponse = session.get(BASEURL + '/api/webserver/SesTokInfo')
 if reqresponse.status_code == 200:
       _dict = xmltodict.parse(reqresponse.text).get('response', None) #here is the correct method to get sessionid and token values

 post_data = '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>\n'
 post_data += '<request><PageIndex>1</PageIndex><ReadCount>'+nb+'</ReadCount><BoxType>1</BoxType><SortType>0</SortType><Ascending>0</Ascending><UnreadPreferred>1</UnreadPreferred></request>\n'

 headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8','Cookie': _dict['SesInfo'],
        '__RequestVerificationToken': _dict['TokInfo']
              } ' in the header i m using the correct values of sessionId and Token
 api_url = BASEURL + '/api/sms/sms-list'
 logonresponse = session.post( api_url, data=post_data, headers=headers)
 result = BeautifulSoup(logonresponse.text, 'html.parser')

 for r in result:
    print(r)
```